# webpack: 'import' not working whereas 'require' works okay

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

I have a strange issue using webpack.

This my webpack.config.js:

```js
import webpack from "webpack";
import path from "path";

//not working: import ExtractTextPlugin from "extract-text-webpack-plugin";
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

const GLOBALS = {
    "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify("production"),
    __DEV__: false
};

export default {
    debug: true,
    devtool: "source-map",
    noInfo: true,
    entry: "./src/bootstrap",
    target: "web",
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        publicPath: "/",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        root: path.resolve(__dirname),
        alias: {
            "~": "src"
        },
        extensions: ["", ".js", ".jsx"]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin(GLOBALS),
        new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.jsx?$/, include: path.join(__dirname, "src"), loaders: ["babel"] },
            { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: "file" },
            { test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/, loader: "file-loader?prefix=font/&limit=5000" },
            { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: "file-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream" },
            { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: "file-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml" },
            { test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i, loaders: ["file"] },
            { test: /\.ico$/, loader: "file-loader?name=[name].[ext]" },
            {
                test: /(\.css|\.scss)$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("css?sourceMap!sass?sourceMap")
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

As you can see: I set up an alias `"~"` pointing to my `"src"` directory.

According to webpack documentation I should be able to import modules this way:

```js
import { ServiceStub } from "~/utilities/service-stub";
```

HINT: File `service-stub.js` sits here: `[__dirname]/src/utilities/service-stub.js`.

However, this does not work since webpack is throwing an error ("Path not found.").

When I use`require` instead of `import`, everything works fine:

```js
const { ServiceStub } = require("~/utilities/service-stub");
```

The same issue is in `webpack.config.js` itself:

```js
import webpack from "webpack";
import path from "path";

//not working: import ExtractTextPlugin from "extract-text-webpack-plugin";
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
```

Here some modules import well with `import` (modules `webpack` and `path`), some do not (module `extract-text-webpack-plugin`).

I worked through dozens of forums, but found no solution yet.

Comment: The first imports the named export, the second - destructures require'd object. So they are not equivalent.

Comment: But even if I write `const ServiceStub = require("~/utilities/service-stub").ServiceStub;` it does not work.

Comment: It's hard to give particular advices about code that is not shown. How exactly does `service-stub.js` export `ServiceStub`?

Comment: Export is done this way: `export { ServiceStub, ProcessingMode };`. BTW: The import works okay with ES6-`import` if I use relative paths: `import { ServiceStub } from "../../utilities/service-stub";`. But I wanted to avoid relative paths.

Comment: Oh right, I've misread your question. Any chance `import { ServiceStub } from "src/utilities/service-stub";` works fine? (I believe it should not) If it does not - try to add `resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', '.'],
    }` to the webpack config

Comment: Not working: `Unable to resolve path to module 'src/utilities/service-stub'`. But I'll try the `modulesDirectories` thing.

Comment: Adding `modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', '.']` to `resolve` did not work. :-(

Comment: It should have. If the project root directory contains both webpack config and `src` directory - it would have been found.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working. The project is based on the boilerplate found here: https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot. Even if I use the virginal boilerplate (without my own code) it does not work. I suspect babel for not intercepting the ES6-`import` in the same way as webpack does it with `require`.

Comment: That's actually the reason I strongly against of using boilerplates: you have a trivial issue with config that normally works (the suggested solution works and always worked for me), but due to artificial complexity of a boilerplate you cannot solve it (or it costs too much time). I'd suggest reporting an issue on the github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is ESLint - not webpack.

When you are using aliases in webpack like this

```
resolve: {
    root: path.resolve(__dirname),
    alias: {
        "~": "src"
    },
    extensions: ["", ".js", ".jsx"]
}
```

and you are importing this way

```
import { ServiceStub } from "~/services/service-stub";
```

ESLint cannot resolve the alias and reports an error.

**To get it work you must tell ESLint to ignore some rule** with `"import/no-unresolved": 0`. This seems to be okay because if an imported file is actually missing, webpack reports an error itself.